# Implementing a feature to track if the user is repeating a search

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post-redirect-get

I have a view model that represents all the fields available for searching.  I'd like to add some logic that would be able to identify if the search values are all the same and determine whether to hit the DB again for their query.

I think I would have to do something like..

- after user submits form save form values to some
  temporary field.
- upon second submission compare temp value to form values collection.
- if values are equal set property in view
  model IsSameSearch = true

I'd like to use the Post Redirect Get Pattern too. So that My search View doesn't do anything except post the form values to another action that processes and filters the data, which is then "Getted" using Ajax.

The SearchViewModel contains many many search parameters.  Here is an abbreviated version.

```
    public bool UseAdvancedSearch { get; set; }
    public bool isSameSearch { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the page.
    /// </summary>
    [HiddenInput]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int Page { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string SortOption { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the address keywords.
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name="Address")]
    public string AddressKeywords { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the census.
    /// </summary>
    public string Census { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the lot block sub.
    /// </summary>
    public string LotBlockSub { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the owner keywords.
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name="Owner")]
    public string OwnerKeywords { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the section township range.
    /// </summary>
    public string SectionTownshipRange { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the strap.
    /// </summary>
    ///
    [Display(Name="Account Number/Parcel ID")]
    public string Strap { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the subdivision.
    /// </summary>
    public string Subdivision { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the use code.
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Use Code")] 
    public string UseCode { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the zip code.
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name="Zip Code")]
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
```

Comment: So to be clear, you want a "cache" pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting data from Entity Framework you could cache the data at EF level. Look at the package entity framework extended https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended. It is as simple as adding method .FromCache () to the query you use to retrieve and filter the data and it will cache the query result.  Make sure you load all the data required using includes etc.

You wouldn't have to worry about same search in model as the caching provider would look at filter settings and determine that it was different. Alternatively cache the data before filtering and then filter the cached results. This is more appropriate if you have lots of filter parameters with significant variance as you will only have to cache 1 large result rather than thousands of smaller results.

You can get more advanced and specify cache period e.g. Cache for 10 minutes

Comment: How big of a result set can be cached? Users can search from a simple home page on the parent models attribute, as well as grand-child attributes.  ~280k records, the searches performed, sort of cross models.  like they can search building type, but that is a property of Building which is a child<List> of Parcel

Comment: EF Caching would take about 15 minutes to setup. Guess it depends on how hard to integrate. Then you could see how big the cache object cache it creates is. Also it would be possible to cache some parts and not others - it is heavily app dependent. It also comes down to what sort of server you are using. We use Azure and just cache all these sort of things on our cache cluster. Our largest record set is 85000 rows but it caches quite happily and we perform searches on the parent of the rows and the child rows based on about 40 criteria.

Comment: Thanks, that brings up a point I'm not clear on.  Do you just cache the searchable stuff, then hit the db to pull records?  What's the "Pattern" for big fancy searches, look at realtor.com as an example.

Comment: We cache entire object graph (85000 records and related). When a search comes in it goes to the query to get the data if a cached version exists then it is used. We apply no filtering here. We filter the result in the next step. As so many parameters that are rarely used it makes sense for us to cache everything for a period of time and searches don't have to be real-time. If it was realtor.com I'd filter the top level and cache that e.g. filter sales vs for rent. I'd never filter on price as it would be to many separate queries, but may filter bedrooms and cache that as it's a narrow range

Comment: Other advice would be to store a denormalized view for search so there are no joins. You could re-generate the denormalized data. Look at CQRS or a dedicaed reporting database that holds a denormalized/optimized version of your search data

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean you'd never filter on price? I have this exact scenario. I have to filter on price ranges.

Comment: Don't cache the query filtered with varying range values. It will create to many cached versions as there are to many permutations.

Comment: Let me know if you need anything else - we found the caching thing quite tricky to get right when we started. Remember to up vote the answer if it has helped :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is called caching.

One way to accomplish that in your scenario would be to implement `GetHashCode()` in a way that it would take into account all your fields/properties to compute a unique value. That way you can use your Hash as the key entry in your cache, and store the results with that key.

For that actual caching you could just use the [`MemoryCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) class provided by the .Net Framework if you are not deploying to a web farm.

Also, if you are familiar with IoC and DI (such as using Unity), things like this can be implemented as an Interceptor, and only requiring you to add an attribute to the method you'd like to cache. That way you implement caching only once as a cross-cutting concern and not fill up your application code with things like this.